# Negative of a number

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic

I understand $-x$ to be the additive inverse of $x$ and vice versa. But looking at an example in my book, it says $-x$ = $-(x)$. Is that quite literally a result of the fact that negative $x$ is equal to the negation of $x$ or is there an alternative reasoning to it?

Comment: I think it's nothing. Just $x=(x)$.

Comment: I don't believe having the addition of parentheses adds anything to it I'm afraid. I agree with @MichaelRozenberg and it would only apply if there is more information within the brackets

Comment: I think it's noting that because if you have say 5-6 you can do 5+(-6) and such. just another way of notating the fact that subtraction allows you to switch signs in parentheses.

Comment: which if x was an expression would help.

Comment: @Morgan The example was to show the place value expansion of -741, so it was shown $(-741) = -(741) = -(700 + 40 + 1) = (-700) + (-40) + (-1).$ Which is fine but I don't understand what is the general reason for going from (-741) to -(741).

Comment: in this case it was just sign switching but if these were variables it might help like I said if x=2*w+z then -x=-(2*w+z)= -1 * (2*w+z)= -2*w-z allows you to take it out of the parentheses when evaluating algebraic expressions.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee So essentially if we have $(-741) = [-(700+40+1)]$. That is literally what was done? As in, the 741 was replaced by 700 + 40 + 1.

Comment: well that's like what you did.

Comment: Why has no one answered this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just multiplicative associative property.
$$-x=-1\cdot x$$
And by the aforementioned property,
$$-1\cdot x=-(x)$$
Thus,
$$-x=-(x)$$